Predicting spelling errors: how should the noisy channel be modeled?
I'm interested in using the noisy channel approach to do spelling correction.  I'm particularly interested in using this technique when a spelling mistake results in another existing word.  E.g. imagine if someone types "NUCLEAR" when they meant to write "UNCLEAR".
The noisy channel approach would incorporate both the prior probability of each word, as well as the probability of the noise separating the sequences (1 transposition in the case of UNCLEAR, no errors in the case of NUCLEAR).
However, depending on how granular our noise probability function is, we might end up with a much lower probability for "UNCLEAR".
$$P(\text{UNCLEAR}) = P(\text{UNCLEAR})\cdot P(\text{1 transposition})$$
$$P(\text{UNCLEAR}) = P(\text{UNCLEAR})\cdot P(\text{1 transposition at characters 1 and 2})$$
In the above, for example, if our noise model ignores the position of the error, we end up with a much higher probability for UNCLEAR, whereas, if our noise model considers position, then UNCLEAR is judged far less likely.
How granular should our noise probability function be?
